# Why is .each repeating the array after completion in my rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops, foreach, acts-as-taggable-on

In my rails view page, I have the following loop that should loop through my tag_list array and print each tag:

```
<%= @user.profile.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
    <%= tag %>
<% end %>
```

For some reason, it repeats the array after it prints each individual tag.  For example, this array has two elements:

```
["ruby", "python"]
```

The output of the each method is  "rubypython ruby,python".  The output should just be "ruby python".  How do I fix this?

By the way, I am using the acts-as-taggable-on gem to generate the tags, but that should not make a difference since it is just a simple array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should remove the equals sign

```
<%= @user.profile.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
```

to

```
<% @user.profile.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
```

the embedded ruby is printing your each block after it's run, so you're getting results of `.each` being run as well as the `tag`

Comment: Great, thanks.  I can't believe it was that simple.